# Is there a way to see who ran pods/jobs in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

When I do `kubectl top pods` I only see NAME, CPU and MEMORY.

```
NAME                                                 CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)   
bbox-inference-falcon-79dc678d8c-2fq9b               4m           1272Mi          
bbox-inference-falcon-79dc678d8c-2nfnk               3m           1503Mi          
bbox-inference-falcon-79dc678d8c-4579l               27m          1303Mi          
bbox-inference-falcon-79dc678d8c-4kjsz               3m           1032Mi          
bbox-inference-falcon-79dc678d8c-4mvxd               3m           1258Mi          
bbox-inference-falcon-79dc678d8c-4pw2t               3m           1115Mi
```

I'd like to know who ran these jobs but `kubectl describe pod pod_name` doesn't give me the information.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use Kubernetes Auditing: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/

Set the Level to Metadata

```
apiVersion: audit.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Policy
rules:
 — level: Metadata
```

Metadata will log: user, resource_name and timestamp